# Estimation of coefficients of variables x when the sum of the x is equal to y

Tags: regression, estimation, mean

I'm a new beginner in learning statistics, and I have an issue with the estimation of coefficients.

To begin with, let's suppose I have 3 observations and 4 explanatory variables:

First observation: y=10 and x1=5, x2=3 and x3=2.
Second observation: y=13 and x1=7, x2=5 and x3=1.
Thirs observation: y=17 and x1=9, x2=4 and x3=4.

Obviously, y is the sum of x.

So my question is: if I want to estimate the coefficients of x for the future values of y, how can I do?

=> a linear regression?

=> calculate the proportion of every x regarding y and make the mean for the three observations? if yes arithmethic mean or harmonic?

=> Or an other method?

Just to precise: I can fix my Y in the future, for example y=27, but what I want to know is, if my Y=27 than what would be the accurate values for X1, X2 and X3.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Why estimate the coefficients at all?  You know they are all equal to one a priori... I'm sure I'm missing something, though.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, the thing is i have a lot of value of y (that I can forecast for example) but only those three values for X1, X2 and X3. That's why I would like to know how can I estimate the coefficients for the Xs.

Comment: Based on the values you have, all the coefficients are 1

Comment: Thanks for the answers, may be it's not the coefficient that I'm looking for then but maybe the proportions???